# Why HEVC format requires Dual-Core CPU?

Tags: codec, cpu, video-player

I have an Intel Core i3 CPU m 380 @253GHz, and I had tried to play a HEVC file in VLC; it played but not smoothly(RAM is 4GB).

However, I have another laptop of with Pentium R Dual-Core CPU T4500 @2.30GHz  (RAM is 2GB). And the same HEVC file plays smoothly on this system.

Both shares Integrated Intel Graphics Chip.

Comment: You should ask this question to the developers of the HEVC-codec...

Comment: @Rafael Do you have their number?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are capable of using a search engine ;)

Comment: @Rafael Google told me to ask Rafael. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, both of those processors are a 2010 vintage, and HEVC is a relatively new format, however it certainly doesn't *require* a dual core.

**Neither are performing better, the graphics on the i3 is a 5 year old integrated chip, whereas the Pentium didn't have integrated, so the dedicated card from around the same time is out performing it, as it should be.**

```
         | Pentium T4500 | Core i3-380M
---------|---------------|--------------
Release  | Q1/2010       | Q3/2010
Cores    | 2             | 2
Threads  | 2             | 4
Speed    | 2.3 GHz       | 2.53 GHz
Graphics | None          | Integrated (667 MHz)
```

Notably, the [Intel Pentium T4500](http://ark.intel.com/products/42925/Intel-Pentium-Processor-T4500-1M-Cache-2_30-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) is listed without a Graphics processor, but with two cores, whereas the [Intel Core i3-380M](http://ark.intel.com/products/50178/Intel-Core-i3-380M-Processor-3M-Cache-2_53-GHz) is listed not only as two cores but running four threads. The slowdown is likely the integrated graphics on the i3-380M unit which by today's standards are ancient, and will likely have issues playing most HD video, regardless of format, although that is HEVCs primary use.

The reason the older, slower, and less threads (same amount of cores, 2) Pentium is winning out is because that model *doesn't* have integrated graphics, and as such will be using a dedicated card.

Comment: Even 1080p videos play well on i3 process. It's only with the HEVC. And if i3 have 2 core, then why it is not called dual-Core?

Comment: There official names are Intel® Pentium® Processor T4500 and Intel® Core™ i3-380M Processor. Intel never puts "dual" or "quad" in there product titles, that's added by the marketing people at whoever manufactured the device.

Comment: As I said, HEVC is newer, and optimised for graphics cards with hardware support, everything else is effectively a legacy device.